# Why the static library is being used twice to make the compilation work?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am learning ARToolKit and also CMake. I am trying to make a CMake routine to replicate what ARToolKit did in their Makefile file.  I found this :

```
LIBS= -lARgsub_lite -lARvideo -lAR -lARICP -lAR -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lX11 -lm -lpthread -ljpeg -ldc1394 -lraw1394

$(BIN_DIR)/simpleLite: simpleLite.o $(OBJS)
cc -o $(BIN_DIR)/simpleLite simpleLite.o $(OBJS) $(LDFLAG) $(LIBS)
```

I notice that `-lAR` is being declared **twice**. I decided to replicate this in my CMake file, also declared twice.

```
set( ART_STATICS libARgsub_lite.a libARvideo.a libAR.a libARICP.a libAR.a)
link_directories(${ART_DIR}/lib)
```

Which it works. But if I remove the last one that is the duplicate, then the program complain that it cannot find function from libAR library. (To be exact it is matrix function in matrix.h of libAR) Why is that? Is the order matter? Or it is possible that `libARICP.a` is "consuming" something in `libAR.a` so you have to declare it again? Sorry I don't understand the inner workings of linking static libraries...

Comment: Yes, order matters. There may be dependencies between the libraries so they have to be handled this way.

Comment: Rather than having duplicates, you should consider using -start-group and  --end-group to specify circular dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find this analogy an especially helpful explanation to what you are asking about ([Source](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html)):

> - Think of an archive library as a bookshelf, with   some books on it (the separate .o files).
> - Some books may refer you to other books   (via unresolved symbols), which may be on the   same, or on a different bookshelf.
>
> A librarian comes to the first bookshelf (the first archive library on
>   your link line) with two lists -- a list of things she still needs
>   (unresolved symbols), and a list of things she already has (symbols
>   already defined).
>
> Usually, she will already have crt0.o (added to the link line by the
>   compiler driver), which refers to main. So her "need" list contains
>   main. Often she will have main.o as well, which means she no longer
>   needs main, but probably needs malloc, free, printf, etc.
>
> Now she starts to scan one bookshelf at a time looking for books that
>   define symbols she needs. If a book defines one of the symbols on the
>   "need" list, she takes that book from the shelf, scratches off all
>   symbols defined in that book from the "need" list, adds all defined
>   symbols to the "have" list, and adds all symbols used by that book and
>   not already in the "have" list to the "need" list.
>
> If a book does not define any symbols currently in the "need" list,
>   she does not take it (even though this book may come in handy later).
>
> If a book she just took defines a symbol she already has, there is
>   "multiply-defined symbol" problem.
>
> If she took any books from the current shelf, she re-scans the shelf
>   again, looking for more books to take (because the books  she just
>   took may need other books on the current shelf).
>
> Once there are no more books she needs on the current shelf, she is
>   done with that shelf, and she does not return to it  (unless the
>   library corresponding to it is listed on the command line several
>   times).
>
> If, after searching all the bookshelves listed on command line (as
>   well as libc which is added by the compiler driver), she still has
>   entries in the "need" list, there is an "undefined symbol" error.
>
> Clearly, if many of your biology books refer to chemistry books, and
>   you've got a biology paper to write, you better start searching the
>   biology bookshelf before the chemistry one.
>
> Sometimes, two archive libraries are inter-dependent: objects from one
>   depend on objects from the other, and vice versa.
>
> This means, that there is no correct order of linking such libraries,
>   that both libraries are poorly structured, and that in order to
>   successfully link an executable, you may need to list both of these
>   libraries several times, as in:
>
> ```
>  gcc main.o -lfoo -lbar -lfoo -lbar -lfoo
> ```
>
> On systems using GNU ld one can use the --start-group and
>   --end-group command-line options to work around such inter-library dependencies.